# pull numbers from a string into an array

Tags: c#

I want to isolate the numbers out of a string but not just single digit numbers:

```
string input = "15, 26, 5, 9, 23"
```

so that in the end it's like:

```
numbers[1] = 15 
numbers[2] = 26
numbers[3] = 5
numbers[4] = 9
numbers[5] = 23
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming they are all numbers:

```
List<int> nums = input.Split(',').Select(numStr => int.Parse(numStr)).ToList();
```

If not, you can simply use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @Selman22 - I've updated even though it passes on Linqpad. Is there any chance that int.Parse removes whitespaces?

Comment: There's no need to use `Trim`, `int.Parse` filters whitespace.

Comment: it seems it uses  NumberStyles.Integer and it allows leading and trailing whitespace. so yes no need for Trim, my bad.

Comment: Yes, if you use the form that passes a `NumberStyles` value for greater control then it may or may not allow whitespace, but the default is that it does.